# MySQL : Concat in where clause not working

Tags: mysql

I am facing a strange problem in mysql while searching multiple columns at once.

`select * from postal_address where concat(address1, ' ', address2) = 'ABC DEF';`

The above query returns data perfectly but the following doesn't return any data

`select * from postal_address where concat(address1, ' ', address2) != 'ABC DEF';`

I have other rows which have null values in the table for those columns.

Comment: Provide sample data for above query

Comment: If you have `null` values then you need to compare *null-safe*.

`select * 
from postal_address 
where coalesce(concat(address1, ' ', address2), '') <> 'ABC DEF'`

Comment: Thanks juergen :) That worked ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following queries should work

```
select * from postal_address where concat(address1, ' ', address2) NOT LIKE 'ABC DEF';

select * from postal_address where concat(address1, ' ', address2) <> 'ABC DEF';
```

In MySQL, `<>` symbol refers to **Not Equal to**

Hope it helps!